# Are there alternatives to MPE if I use MPI?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich

Are there any alternatives to use something other than MPE if I want to draw in a window with all processes while I use MPI?

Answer (score 2):

MPE is a little bit more than the call tracing part of MPICH.  There is a Java-based viewer called Jumpshot.  In the past there was upshot, nupshot, etc. I don't know how much fun it would be to resurrect those old bits of software.

The "Using MPI-1" book has a bit about rendering a mandelbrot set with MPE drawing primitives, and might point you in a productive direction.

These routines are quite old.  I don't know if they still work.

```
MPE_Open_graphics
MPE_Draw_point
MPE_Draw_line
MPE_Draw_circle
MPE_Fill_rectangle
MPE_Update
MPE_Num_colors
MPE_Make_color_array
MPE_Close_graphics
```

You can find an example of their use over in the MPE git repository:

http://git.mpich.org/mpe.git/tree/HEAD:/src/graphics/contrib/mandel

I don't think this code has even been compiled in a decade.